# How to bundle old plain JS files in Vite

Tags: migration, vite

I have an app I want to start converting to ViteJS.

The problem is there are around 50 JS files that are not modules - they rely on the global window object. There are lots of global classes, and there's also a global "App" object that multiple files modify.

I've looked over the docs and I'm pretty thoroughly confused about including raw JS in the bundle file.

I was hoping to find a config where I can include them all in the bundled JS file so I don't need to worry about caching and minimize the number of HTTP requests.

Optimally, it would load each file, minify it (if possible), and include them at the top of the index-....js file.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I've seen the import method, but it seems like that is for modules with exports. I've also tried some options to include the files from the public directory, but it's pretty messy and doesn't bundle them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the public directory](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory).

you can move your JavaScript files that are not modules there, and they will be copied as-is to the `dist/` folder